# Relation between measures of macroscopicity and quantum computation speed up

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, superposition

In quantum information theory, a macroscopic quantum superposition state is a state of the form

\begin{equation}
|\Psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|A\rangle+|B\rangle),
\end{equation}
where $|A\rangle$ and $|B\rangle$ are two macroscopic sectors of the state $|\Psi\rangle$ (one can have more such sectors). One of the requirements for the state $|\Psi\rangle$ to represent a macroscopic quantum superposition is that the two macroscopic sectors should be "macroscopically distinguishable". Various measures of such macroscopically distinguishability have been proposed in the literature. One of the importance of such macroscopic quantum superposition states, that has been mentioned in the literature, is their use in implementing  quantum computing algorithms that will speed up the performance of the algorithm.  I am trying to understand this relationship?

Comment: "I am trying to understand this relationship?" is not really a question. Can you try to pinpoint what you are really asking - as written it's asking for a book chapter.